# Can no longer not to Windows 10 on m.2 nvme drive after installing a sata ssd

Tags: windows-10, boot

I had been using a m.2 nvme drive as my windows 10 boot drive without any problems. I installed an old sata SSD that I had lying around and now I can no longer not to Windows on the nvme drive.

The old SSD had an old installation of Windows 10 on it.

After I installed the SSD, no boot options were visible in the BIOS. Boot options did become available once I enabled CSM, (this was previously disabled and wasn't a problem before), with CSM enabled I am able to boot to the old windows installation on the SSD but if I choose to boot from the nvme drive I get an error

"reboot and select proper boot device"

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the nvme drive, it's recognised in the bios and I can access the files on it.

I'm using a 3950x, Asus x570 tuf motherboard and sabrant nvme drive.

Comment: In my opinion it's not a good idea to have two Windows 10 installations on different drives on the same PC.  I think it would be better to remove the Windows 10 installation from the slowest drive and use it only for data or backup